# a not significant result from Mann Whitney U and Kruskal-Wallis test despite large difference in sample median values

Tags: p-value, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I was really hoping someone could assist me with this as I can't find anything in my books/papers/online. I know from descriptive statistics that there is a large median difference in earnings between two groups of men and women (2 groups of men, before and after, and two groups of women, before and after). My sample size for men is larger (500) than for women (120) and the effect of the change on the median is an increase for men and a decrease for women, but the size of the differences is considerable for both. Yet when I run tests for differences in median or distribution, I'm only getting a significant result for men and not for women (men p ,.05, women p value .6!). 
I'd really appreciate if anyone could shed any light on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: These are not tests of differences between medians so it's hard to say what's behind your results. You'd probably be better off with standard parametric statistics. See: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10459-010-9222-y

Comment: If you would post summary statistics for each group (say median and interquartile range, or even mean and standard deviation) it would be easier to say whether the result is unbelievable. Also, from your description it sounds like this might be a paired test, in which case you want Wilcoxon signed rank, not Mann Whitney.

Comment: These tests do not test for differences in medians -- you can have significant Mann-Whitney when the medians are equal and Mann-Whitney p-values of 1 when the medians look very different. Are your data paired (are they the same people before and after?) -- if so, you should not be using tests for independent samples.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The samples (groups) are actually independent (those with children and those without). The descriptives are: Men before children: median €21,216, IQR: €13,513 - €38,738 after children median €28,200 IQR: €15,980 - €46,751. Women before children: median €18,716 IQR €11,384-€25,795, after children median €14,116 IQR: €9,100- €25,139. I can't use mean as the distribution of earnings is non-normal and also I think too impacted by outliers....

Answer (score 1):

Significance tests are partly an effect of sample size.  They are way over-emphasized and answer a question we are rarely interested in:

> If, in the population from which this sample was randomly drawn, the
>   true effect was zero, how probable is it that we would get a test
>   statistic at least as extreme as the one we got in a sample the size
>   of the one we have?

So, if the effect size was about equal for men and women, it is entirely reasonable that it was significant for men and not women.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Yes, I guess because the female sample size was considerably smaller than the male, there was a greater probability that the result could have been by chance (I may not have worded that very well but you know what I mean). It goes against the theory (motherhood penalty in earnings) and results of previous research but I will need to examine the data more closely before I can report anything on it.